# Why eclipse showing error but not IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I usually work with IntelliJ but recently one of my team mate opened project in eclipse and he found eclipse showing error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to boolean` in 2 separate java files. I crossed checked in IntelliJ but no error.

Below are the screenshot from Eclipse and IntelliJ respectively:

Eclipse:

[image]

IntelliJ

[image]

I also checked that both the IDEs have same compiler compliance level, i.e. 11

Eclipse:

[image]

IntelliJ

[image]

Even though Eclipse is showing error, if I run the project in eclipse then build and run is successful.

As in above actual code example `row` object is created from an interface, I do not have access to see it's actual implementation. Hence just to generate the scenario so that I can understand why and how two different IDEs behave differently ? I have created below reproducible example:

IRow.java:

```
public interface IRow {
    <T> T getValue();
}
```

RowImpl.java

```
public class RowImpl implements IRow {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> T getValue() {
        return (T) Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}
```

and the main.java

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        IRow row = new RowImpl();
        if(row.getValue()) //--> Eclipse shows error but IntelliJ not
            System.out.println("value is true");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what was the error that it was complaining about ... ?

Comment: @StephenC Oh, forgot to mention it's `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to boolean`

Comment: And what type is returned by `row.getValue(...)` ?  (Or ... what is the type of `row`?)

Comment: row.getValue(...) returns `Object`

Comment: Well ... that is the cause of your problem!  You can't use an `Object` as the condition of an `if` statement.

Comment: `<T> T getValue(IContext context, int columnIndex);` is the definition of  `getValue()`

Comment: @StephenC but then why IntelliJ is not complaining about the same? and even in Eclipse if build/run the project then it's successful.

Comment: It would appear that there is a difference between the IDEs' compilers.  Could you please write a minimal reproducible example for this.  So that we can try it out with other compilers, and check what the JLS says about it ...

Comment: @StephenC "there is a difference between the IDEs' compilers." --> If you mean by JDK/JRE refereed in build path then both are referring to the same JDK folder. About the reproducible example, let try to create it.

Comment: PLEASE include a [mre] in the question - we have no idea how `row` is declared, we have no idea how `T` is being inferred (or not) as return value of `getValue`, ....

Comment: The type of `row.getValue(..)` depends on the generics bound determined by the compiler for whatever `roq` might be, which you did not include in your paste. Hence, this question cannot be answered. Intellij binds it to 'boolean', ecj evidently does not. The error is elsewhere and this clause merely triggers it, it is not itself the cause. A full reproducible example is the next step :)

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yes, I am preparing reproducible example. Though, I don't have access to see how `getValue()` is implemented, We are creating object of an interface which has this method. But, according to my best knowledge I will create a example.

Comment: Note: Eclipse uses its own compiler "ecj" rather than "javac", this can occasionally give different results. We need a full example to be able to tell which compiler is correct.

Comment: Hello there [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m61RPr6ytENlMBbHulod-5KTAH6VOR9g/view?usp=sharing) is the reproducible example.

Comment: As I said already, I don't have access to see implementation of `getValue()`. In reproducible example, I have just reproduced the error. Because I wanted to understand why and how both IDEs treat the same line of code differently

Comment: @greg-449 I checked on this point as well. In IntelliJ if I change compiler to `Eclipse` then also IntelliJ does not show error.

Comment: @rzwitserloot reproducible example added. Your help will be appreciated to understand why both IDE treats same line of code differently

Comment: @StephenC reproducible example added. Your help will be appreciated to understand why both IDE treats same line of code differently  .

Comment: @greg-449 Question updated with example code. Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse uses its own compiler, distinct from javac, and this error appears to be the manifestation of a difference in compiler implementation.

This is the ticket raised on their issue tracker. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513766

Eclipse compiler devs seem to consider it a bug in javac, rather than the other way around. So perhaps the question should be "why does javac accept it"? This ticket exists for the JDK https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8179483, and was raised by Dan Smith who is a language designer at Oracle. He states that "javac should reject this program".

That said, I'd be quite surprised if they remove this "feature". Oracle are not in the habit of making backwards-incompatible changes, which this would be for people like you. A more likely solution seems an adjustment to the spec to allow for it, but I'd bet it's more complex than it seems on the surface, or they might have addressed it by now.

I think effectively this behaviour is ambiguously defined, and you should ideally avoid relying on it. I'd change your code to

```
if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(row.getValue()))
```

Comment: Oh! that's really very complex. But, according to you who is more accurate/correct eclipse or javac. After reading your answer and ticket I feel Eclipse team is correct because JLS [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) says that "Expression must have type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs. " What do you think?

Comment: @Amogh That part of the spec isn't in disagreement. By declaring your method as `<T> T foo()`, you're stating "this can return whatever type the caller asks for", which is obviously a bit strange since it actually *always* returns a boolean regardless of what type the caller asks for. That logical inconsistency is what leads to you having to suppress the unchecked cast warning. But assuming your method could return whatever type the caller wanted, then it can return Boolean, which would satisfy that part of the spec.

Comment: @Amogh The problem is actually related to whether an if-statement is *allowed* to infer its expression to be boolean. I believe the spec doesn't say. The javac implementation does, and the Eclipse implementation does not. It seems somewhat reasonable to me, but it seems to be working by accident - by treating the expression as an assignment, which it's not.

Comment: Thanks Michael detailed explanation. I will change my code to cast the value first then use as `expression`.